# Inserting an image between text in django when both text and image are in the model

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm looking for a way of inserting an image in between the text of my blog made with django. What I want to achieve is something like in the following image:

[image]

As you will see the text is divided in two columns. There are titles, links an image and its caption.

Right now my model is like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body_col1 = models.TextField()
    body_col2 = models.TextField()
    body_col1_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    body_col2_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    image = image = models.ImageField()
```

The text is transformed to markdown so I can add css format in my admin panel. So what I did was to render the variables in the html template using tags:

```
<div class="column-left">
    {{ object.body_col1_html|safe}}
</div>
<div class="column-right">
    {{ object.image}}
    {{ object.body_col1_html|safe}}
</div>
```

Doing that I have the two columns and the image on the top of the second column.

I'm looking for a way to **remove the two fields for the text**, so I have only one text field, where I can add my image inside the text. I have a javascript function that automatically divides the text into two columns. I would like to have something like this:

```
<div class="columns">
    {{ object.body|safe}}
</div>
```

where the body field already have the image inside (the same way I can add css or links).

What I tried so far is to add the tag in the text box like {{object.image}} but, since I'm using markdown, it converts to text so instead of my image I got a useless string.

Is there a way to add the image from the body text box in the admin panel? Could I call a template tag from there?

The code of the django blog is [here](https://github.com/hoaphumanoid/sciblog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is called rich text editor, it will allow you to build external html pages however you want and safe them into a singe field in your database.
One of the most popular editors is CKeditor, I suggest you take a look at at [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already though about that, the problem is that a feature of my blog is that it can use [Latex notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). To do that I have a library that takes the latex notation written in the text, performs a markdown process and then render it with the latex fonts. Therefore I think it might crash if I add the rich text editor. I would give it a try just in case. The rich text editor should make in a way what I want. Do you have any idea of how it does it??

Comment: @HoapHumanoid, I am not sure what you use for rendering, but there is a thing called [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/), it takes Latex notation and process it into html, it quite a common solution for web when speaking of math notation. As for ckeditor there is a addon called [mathjax](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax), it is added to django-ckeditor also.

Comment: thanks yes I use mathjax precisely. It's good that it works together with ckeditor. I will try it

Comment: @pthad budy I finally used your advice and the system is working now. Thanks!!